# Create a template for front end when plugin install

Tags: craft3, plugin-development

I have a plugin which embed a forum to front end website. For that i need a .twig template file to be created when craft admin install my plugin.

The template file will have html code `<div id="myDivId"></div>`, that template will be appear as website page, which can be open by click on one of menu item on top header.

I have research a lot but didn't find a way to create template for front end. And that template must load on front end side only when user click on menu item linked with that template.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend this, as you're taking control away from the developer by forcing a specific template to exist. Craft allows for complete freedom in the way I structure my templates. As a site developer, if I install your plugin and see it creating some random template in my templates folder, I will uninstall your plugin immediately and never touch it again.

Instead, you can provide a function to Twig that I can include in my own code, wherever I choose to. This will allow me to integrate your plugin's output into my own templates on my own terms – for example, by only showing your plugin's output in specific circumstances. For example, you can provide a function `myPluginHtml()` function that I can call in my Twig template and that returns the HTML code required by your plugin:

```
{{ myPluginHtml() }}
```

Look at [Extending Twig](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/extending-twig.html) for details. You can still write your plugin templates in Twig, but put them in the plugin's template folder, not the *site's* template folder. See [template roots](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/template-roots.html) for more details.

Comment: MoritzLost, You are right. I don't want to create a physical template to template forlder. I have created template folder in my plugin and render it to the front end and set route using URLManager and EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES

Comment: @KishanMistry That sounds like a good solution! If your question is solved, don't forget to mark the answer accepted. Thanks!